# Select Comparando Periodos

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Estou precisando fazer um `select` que compara dois períodos de vendas, totalizando por produto.
Hoje tenho esse `select` que faz isso, mas somente para um período (01/09/2014 a 30/09/2014)

```
SELECT ACC.PRODUTODESC  PRODUTO,
       Sum(ACC.VALORTARIFA) + 0.0 VALORA,
       Count(ACC.ID) + 0.0 TRANSACOESA
FROM BASEDADOSPADRAO ACC
WHERE ACC.DATAEMISSAO BETWEEN '20140901' and '20140930'
AND ACC.CLIENTE in (21333)
GROUP BY ACC.PRODUTODESC
```

que me dá o seguinte resultado:

```
PRODUTO        VALORA     TRANSACOESA
Carro         4093.96             1.0
Miscelâneos  18806.35            15.0
Aéreo       378076.11           701.0
Hotel       230376.81           264.0
```

Preciso juntar o resultado do mesmo `select`, porém de um outro período (01/09/2015 a 30/09/2015) para que o resultado fosse algo parecido com o que tem abaixo

```
PRODUTO        VALORA     TRANSACOESA          VALORB     TRANSACOESB
Carro         4093.96             1.0            NULL            NULL     
Miscelâneos  18806.35            15.0         7182.23             3.0
Aéreo       378076.11           701.0       275637.66           443.0  
Hotel       230376.81           264.0       177826.98           204.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz as duas consultas separadamente e depois com um `LEFT JOIN` juntei o resultado das duas.

```
 SELECT T1.PRODUTO, T1.VALORA, T1.TRANSACOESA, T2.VALORB, T2.TRANSACOESB FROM 
(SELECT ACC.PRODUTODESC  PRODUTO,
           Sum(ACC.VALORTARIFA) + 0.0 VALORA,
           Count(ACC.ID) + 0.0 TRANSACOESA
    FROM BASEDADOSPADRAO ACC
    WHERE ACC.DATAEMISSAO BETWEEN '20140901' and '20140930'
    AND ACC.CLIENTE in (21333)
    GROUP BY ACC.PRODUTODESC) AS T1 LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT ACC.PRODUTODESC  PRODUTO,
           Sum(ACC.VALORTARIFA) + 0.0 VALORB,
           Count(ACC.ID) + 0.0 TRANSACOESB
    FROM BASEDADOSPADRAO ACC
    WHERE ACC.DATAEMISSAO BETWEEN '20150901' and '20150930'
    AND ACC.CLIENTE in (21333)
    GROUP BY ACC.PRODUTODESC) AS T2 ON T1.PRODUTO = T2.PRODUTO
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo !!! Exatamente isso que precisava. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. Funcionou certinho !!!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Já que a resposta foi útil, se possível vote a favor e marque-a como aceita ;) @AlvaroVieira

Comment: onde eu faço isso ..rsrsr Farei com o maior prazer

Comment: @AlvaroVieira http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta